# Найти слово из файла, в котором встретится больше всего букв из слова, введённого с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, символы

Имеется файл, в нём написаны слова. С клавиатуры вводится слово с неповторяющимися буквами. Найти и вывести слово из файла, в котором встретится больше всего букв из слова, введённого с клавиатуры. 
Никак не могу понять, как можно это реализовать в программе...  Кто-нибудь, подскажите, пожалуйста, возможный алгоритм, желательно без использования изощрённых процедур и малоизвестных библиотек. Что лучше использовать: стринги или чары?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример функции, которая возвращает количество совпадающих символов в строке `s` из строки `sub`:

```
size_t overlap(const string& s, const string& sub)
{
    size_t  k = 0, sz = sub.size();
    for (size_t n = 0; n < sz; ++n){
        k += std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), sub[n]);
    }
    return k;
}
```

Попытайтесь самим написать программу.

Answer (score 1):

Ввести слово, внести символы из слова в `std::set`

Для каждого слова из файла посчитать, сколько символов из него есть в set

Comment: Чем же  std::string не последовательность символов?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Этот вопрос ко мне или он риторический?

Comment: Вопрос вам - для чего нужен set?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Для простого сравнения, хорошего по времени (не лучшего). Вариантов решения множество. Этот займёт всего несколько строчек, использует STL,  а не "малоизвестные библиотеки", чего автор не хочет, не не требует много памяти, и достаточно быстр.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan не подскажете, как посчитать, сколько символов в слове есть в строке string?

Comment: @MBo,  Есть слово  исходное "абракадабра" и есть  условное слово  s1 = "абкд" .  Если последнее упорядочить, получится  s2 =  "абдк".   Не так легко написать альгоритм, который быстрее посчитает сколько  букв совпадают из s2, чем сколько совпадет из s1.  Ну подумайте сами...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Первый метод, о котором я подумал, был именно с упорядочением символов строк.Однако он требует сортировки каждого слова, а метод c set в этом не нуждается. А если set сделать самому как массив bool[alphabetsize], то этот методу будет самым быстрым из возможных.

Comment: @MBo,  тогда вы напишите этот метод в ответе, а мы будем наслаждаться вашим  волшебством.

Answer (score 1):

Вводите слово-образец. 
В цикле, пока не получите отказ, читаете файл пословно, используя fscanf()
Потом для каждой буквы слова проверяете, содержится ли она в образце? используя strchr(). Если содержится добавляете в счетчик. Если слово содержит больше символов из образца, чем предыдущее, сохраняете его. Когда все слова из файла прочитаны, у вас будет сохранено то самое, которое вам нужно. Примерный код, работающий как в C, так и в C++. Вводить слово-образец было лень и я его забил в массив -- для отладки и демонстрации примера достаточно и так.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *ifile;

    if (NULL == (ifile = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(errno);
    }
    int n    = 0;
    int nmax = 0;
    char *ss;
    char smpl_word[] = "sample_word";
    char next_word[1024];
    char most_word[1024];
    // читаем файл словами
    while (1 == fscanf(ifile, "%1023s", next_word)) {
        // сканируем для каждой буквы полученного слова факт
        // вхождения в smpl_word
        ss = next_word;
        n  = 0;
        do { // scanf никогда не возвращает пустых строк
            if (strchr(smpl_word, *ss++)) {
                n++;    // и отмечаем если входит
            }
        } while (*ss);
        // проверка на превышение количеств вхождений
        if (n > nmax) {
            nmax = n;
            strcpy(most_word, next_word);
        }
    }
    // собственно, и все на этом
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", most_word);
    return 0;
    argc++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int getRateWordByPattern(const string& word, const string& pattern)
{
    int rate = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.size(); ++i)
        rate += std::count(word.begin(), word.end(), pattern[i]);

    return rate;
}

void main()
{
    string pattern = "ght";

    ifstream f;
    f.open("D://1.txt");

    if (!f.is_open())
        return;

    int max_rate = 0;
    string res_word = "not found";

    string word;
    while (f >> word)
    {
        int rate = getRateWordByPattern(word, pattern);
        if (rate > max_rate)
        {
            max_rate = rate;
            res_word = word;
        }
    }

    cout << max_rate << endl;
    cout << res_word << endl;

    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
}
```

Накидал тут на коленке. Нет обработки ошибок, данные все забил хардкорно.
Слово с буквами для поиска в переменной pattern.

В файле у меня строка вида: one two three four five six seven eight nine ten.

Ввод данных, валидацию и обработку ошибок встроишь сам и все.

P.S. По поводу оптимизации два пути вижу, либо заранее файл анализировать и строить по нему метаданные, либо более умно считать рейтинг. Насчет последнего надо еще подумать.

Comment: не могли бы вы пояснить, как работает строка "for each (char pattern_ch in pattern)"?

Comment: Использовал компилятор Visual C++ 17, он такую конструкцию поддерживает. Вообще, сама конструкция из CLR, читай C#. Проверил на gcc и clang компиляторах - не понимают.

Comment: В С++ 11 стандарте ввели range-based loops, каноничный синтаксис:
`for (auto& val : container) {...}`
Отличие от стандартного фора в том, что эта конструкция работает через итераторы.

Обновил пример, дабы не смущать. Расписывать отличия в одном комментарии - символов не хватит. Лучше Вам отдельно почитать.

Comment: OMG, как же плохо я знаю C++ и всякие IDE...) Спасибо за правку, теперь гораздо понятнее!